# Angular PWA on Samsung Internet Browser

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Angular version: 13
Samsung Internet version: 16.2.1.56

I developed an Angular application and added PWA. Chrome and Edge display the install icon, but Samsung Internet does not.

I tested the application on the pwabuilder website and everything seems normal.

[image: pwa builder test]

I tried this code and the alert shows `true` even in Samsung browser.

```html
<script>
    alert('serviceWorker' in navigator);
</script>
```

and:

```html
    <button id="btn-install-app" class="btn">Install App</button>
    
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            deferredPrompt = e;
        });
    
        const btnInstallApp = document.getElementById('btn-install-app');
    
        if(btnInstallApp) {
            btnInstallApp.addEventListener('click', e => {
                deferredPrompt.prompt();
                deferredPrompt.userChoice
                    .then(choiceResult => {
                        if(choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                            console.log('user accepted A2HS prompt');
                        } else {
                            console.log('user dismissed A2HS prompt');
                        }
                    deferredPrompt = null;
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

After clicking on the install button, Chrome and Edge show an install prompt, but in Samsung rowser nothing is shown.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am also in the same situation (angular + pwa). In May 2022, it finally seems to work in the latest Samsung browser(ver 17.0.1.69). It's probably a Samsung browser bug.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the samsung browser. Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31696591)